# LC oscillator V.S. LC oscillator deactivation

Tags: power, oscillator, efficiency

I read a paper,and it said using the LC oscillator to start-up will have a very low peak efficiency,about 1%,so they use the LC oscillator deactivation to let the peak efficiency become 33%.And i see their schematic,i think they still use a LC oscillator to start-up.

At first,i thought the meaning of LC oscillator deactivation is that i don't use the LC oscillator,but now it seems not,so i am confused now.

What does  LC oscillator deactivation mean?

What is difference between LC oscillator and LC oscillator deactivation?

The picture below is their schematic for start-up circuit,and i think the left one is a  LC oscillator deactivation they said.

Paper is from :ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7479575/

[image]

Comment: Can you share a circuit diagram of said oscillator, capitalize I and put space after period and comma? Link to where they used a “deactivation”? Did they deactivate some kind of self-oscillating mode and switched to hard-fireing?

Comment: @winny OK,sorry for the missing picture.No,they just show the schematic and said the "LC oscillator deactivation" can have more peak efficiency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LC oscillator deactivation is that LC oscillator + voltage to the mos body,like the picture shown

[image]